# Personalisation between multiple sitecore instance with same or different subdomains

Tags: xdb, personalization, fxm

We have multiple sitecore websites hosted on their own instances with same domains below:

1. mainsite.com
2. siteA.mainsite.com
3. siteB.mainsite.com (with authentication enabled)
4. siteC.mainsite.com

And also on separate domain

1. site2.com

**Requirement** is that when user visits any of the sites we need to identify their interest and personalise the content.

For example, if user vists siteA.mainsite.com, spends quiet of bit of time reading article on specific category item. Then when user visits any of the other sites, show that category item on banner.

What would be the best possible solution to achieve this type of personalisation?

While ago sitecore released the FXM but I'm unsure if this is the best solution as this solution seems to work only in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

In general, historical personalization of users requires the data in xDB. You have a one-to-one relationship between xDB and Master database, so if you migrate your multiple sites into one multi-site authoring environment and publish out to individual content delivery instances and separate web databases, your front-end will still be isolated but you can leverage the full XP platform capabilities.

Based on your question, though, I believe you are trying to achieve in-session personalization between disparate Sitecore topologies by somehow using the same shared session database record between the different sites. I'm not sure this is possible, as I believe each Sitecore instance, regardless of domain, will want to create it's own session.

Comment: Not even with analytics domain cookie and fxm?

Comment: That is an interesting thought, using FXM to tie the systems together. I have not personally done this, but perhaps somebody who has implemented FXM might be able to provide an option for how to accomplish that.

It would stand to reason that with FXM on your site, you could track behaviour and personalize, but this seems like more of a workaround than going for a multi-site implementation?